# How to read from Path line by line into a HashMap

Tags: java, path, hashmap

Hello I'm trying to read a file (words.txt), which contains a large list of english words into a Hashmap.  I'm accessing the file with Paths.  My function passes in a Path that is being opened and attempts to input the contents into a HashMap.  I can print all the values of the Path word by word, but I'm having trouble storing the values into a HashMap.  I'm attempting to make a SpellChecker thats better than my O(n) ArrayList implementation.  Before I attempt to solve it with a Trie or BKTree, I would like to solve it with a HashMap.

Summary: How can I get the word.txt file opened with Path into a HashMap.

## My Code

```
 private static void createMap(Path dictFile) throws Exception{
        Map<Integer,String> theWords = new HashMap<>();
        int count = 0;

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(dictFile)) {
            stream.forEach(theWords.put(count++, stream));
            //stream.forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `count`? Why are you putting `0, stream` into the `Map` repeatedly? You may need to learn about lambdas - you don't seem to be using `forEach` correctly.

Comment: I believe you need to give it a Key (Integer) and a String.

Comment: You're not putting the `String` as a value, you're placing `Stream`. You need to learn about lambdas - you need to take for value passed into the `Consumer<String>` that is the argument to `forEach`. Also, you are just adding items by index into a `Map` - how is that different to a `List`? What are your aims with using the `Map`?

Comment: I'm going to use HashMap to create a SpellChecker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out::println` is a method reference and `theWords.put(count++, stream)` is not. Additionally as already pointed out by Boris the stream would be added to the map, not the individual words.

A correct lambda expression could look like `word -> theWords.put(count++, word)` but this also won't compile due to the `count` variable not being effectively final, it cannot be changed inside a lambda expression.

If the intention is to be able to just quickly look up if a particular word is contained in the dictionary file a `Set` would also be sufficient and the code could look like:

```
HashSet<String> theWords = Files.lines(dictFile)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Then look up words using e.g.

```
theWords.contains("hello");
```

For case insensitive lookups use `() -> new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)` instead of `HashSet::new`.

Comment: So when that returns true - How can I access the actual  value?  Just a theWords.get(value) ?

Comment: I found a work around to just a set a temp to the value your checking if it contains true return the temp strings as found.